# New programmer stuck on elif

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
def computepay(h,r):
    if h <= 40 :
        p = r * h
        print p
    elif hrs >= 40 :
        p = r * 40 + (r * 1.5 * (h - 40) )
        print p
    else :
        Print "Error, you were payed to much"""


hrs = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:"))
# int can only represent whole numbers

rate = int(raw_input("Enter Rate:"))
# float can only represent floating-point values, that is, values that have a potential decimal place.
#r = float(rate)
p = computepay(h, r)
print "Pay",p
```

I'm trying to learn python but cant figure out why I'm getting an error for the `elif` on the `computepay(h, r)` function.

Comment: `hrs` != `h` ... `elif h >= 40`

Comment: in your `else` statement shouldn't it be `print` instead of `Print` ? als you got triple double quotes in the same `print` statement

Comment: The error should tell you exactly what the issue is...

Comment: Near the end, you call `computepay(h, r)`, but `h` and `r` are not defined. Maybe you meant `computepay(hrs, rate)`?

Comment: You can't post a question saying you're getting an "*error*" as that gives us very little to work with.  What is the (full) error message? What line is it on? What about the error is confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives me no errors:

```
def computepay(h,r):
    if h <= 40 :
        p = r * h
        return p
    elif h > 40 :
        p = r * 40 + (r * 1.5 * (h - 40) )
        return p
    else :
        return "Error, you were payed to much"

        h = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:"))
        # int can only represent whole numbers

        r = int(raw_input("Enter Rate:"))
        # float can only represent floating-point values, that is, values that have a potential decimal place.
        #r = float(rate)

        p = computepay(h, r)
        print "Pay",p
```

You are not setting like this `p = computepay(hrs, rate)`, `h` and `r` are not defined so even if you solve your identation errors this will not work until you fix it. And you should return value `p`, its why the output of  `print "Pay",p` is `Pay None`

Comment: You are using an undefined value in your first 'if'

Comment: it was not the second? @stark

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your function `p = computepay(h,r)` you are passing non existing values `h` and `r` ( which are just your signatures for the function ), you'd need to pass `hrs` and `rate` like : `p = computepay(hrs,rate)`

You got a small typo mistake in your `elif` , you typed the variable you meant to use instead of the one you defined as a signature for your function (`h`).

In your function definition you can use `h` which will be replaced with `hrs` when u pass it as an argument.

So your `elif` would be :

`elif h >= 40`

You have an ambiguity in your comparisons :

```
if h <= 40 :
```

Look at the `=`

```
elif h >= 40 :
```

Edit : actually it would go to your `if` but would ignore your `elif` since it already matched.

You also have a typo mistake in your `else` block , it should be `print` instead of `Print` and you also have triple `"` at the end of your string.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about python giving an error on the `elif` line, due to `hrs` not being defined.